# Installing novadocker for openstack

Tags: configuration, docker, openstack, openstack-nova

I have a problem in setting up novadocker, to set up a Docker compute node with Openstack.
Openstack version is Horizon.

I have followed this tutorial https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker#Installing_Docker_for_OpenStack, but when I change the node-compute.conf file accordingly with what is written in the tutorial, I get this error in the log file when I try to start nova-compute service:

```
ImportError: No module named novadocker.virt.docker
```

Do you know what this is due to and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you so much for the help!

Marco

**PS** in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` there is a file called `nova-docker.egg-link` which contains the real location of novadocker driver... It seems it is ignored when nova is looking for it.

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to run `python setup.py install`. Now I've done it but thre is another error I can't solve:

```
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 ERROR nova.virt.driver [-] Unable to load the virtualization driver
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/driver.py", line 1299, in load_compute_driver
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver     virtapi)
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 52, in import_object_ns
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 28, in import_class
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver     __import__(mod_str)
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver     from novadocker.virt.docker import driver
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 31, in <module>
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver     from nova.i18n import _
2014-09-29 14:59:47.233 22982 TRACE nova.virt.driver ImportError: No module named i18n
```

I don't know what this module is and how to fix this problem...

Can anybody help me?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I managed to solve this issue by going backward the last commits, actually this commit https://github.com/stackforge/nova-docker/commit/9ce916c486a64bfac38fb665fbe7619cef4e1f92. But now surprisingly I get this problem:

```
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 ERROR nova.virt.driver [-] Unable to load the virtualization driver
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/driver.py", line 1299, in load_compute_driver
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver     virtapi)
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 52, in import_object_ns
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 28, in import_class
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver     __import__(mod_str)
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver     from novadocker.virt.docker import driver
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novadocker/virt/docker/driver.py", line 41, in <module>
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver     from novadocker.virt.docker import client as docker_client
2014-09-29 17:31:21.667 4979 TRACE nova.virt.driver ImportError: cannot import name client
```

I actually don't know what to do! Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what the problem was. This worked to me:

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/49874/nova-docker-issue-import-error-no-module-named-i18n/

Answer (score 0):

Juno doesn't require limitation like mentioned above :-
$ git checkout -b pre-i18n 9045ca43b645e72751099491bf5f4f9e4bddbb91

View "Running Nova-Docker on OpenStack RDO Juno (CentOS 7 && Fedora 21)"
1. http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/799569-running-nova-docker-on-openstack-rdo-juno-centos-7
2.http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/802013-set-up-nova-docker-on-openstack-rdo-juno-on-top-of-fedora-21/